# CakePHP .ctp syntax highlighting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cakephp

Why CakePHP decided to build their own file format instead of .tpl is beyond me... despite that, i can't get syntax highlighting to work in Eclipse...  I've followed this guide:
<s>http://planetcakephp.org/aggregator/items/5452-opening-ctp-file-with-syntax-highlight-in-eclipse</s> (**dead link**) but it doesn't work, I see an error about an unsupported content type for this file.  I've added an association to the PHP editor for this file type and it still shows the issue.

Any ideas on how to get syntax highlighting to work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure you have set the correct editor associations and content types

Go to settings (`Window -> preferences`)

**Content Types**

1. Type in `Content Types` in the search box (should show under `General -> Types`
2. Click on the arrow next to `Text`, select `PHP Content Type`
3. Add `*.ctp` by clicking on the Add button on the right side

**File Association**

1. Type in `File Associations` in the search box on the left
2. Add *.ctp (click the Add button on the top right side)
3. Associate the proper editor for it by clicking Add (on the bottom right side) and selecting PHP Editor

Comment: On eclipse Indigo you need to restart eclipse, before the new added content type is used.

Comment: After making the above changes, close the file, restart Eclipse, and then open the file. ([source](http://riobautista.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/syntax-highlighting-cakephp-using-eclipse/))

Comment: in file association i had to set as default the php editor for *.ctp

Answer (score 0):

You can change the extension that CakePHP uses for view files to an extension that Eclipse likes.  In the controller (or app_controller) add the following variable:

```
var $ext = '.tpl';
```

If you change the extension to "PHP" you may have problems because CakePHP will try to load a class that matches the filename.