# How can i add syntax highlight in eclipse for cakephp view.ctp files?

Tags: php, eclipse, cakephp, editor, syntax-highlighting

When i start to edit a view file like add.ctp , i don't get any syntax highlight in eclipse.
How can i get syntax highlight for add.ctp ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP .ctp syntax highlighting in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809103/cakephp-ctp-syntax-highlighting-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Navigate to **Window -> Preferences** -> **General -> Content Types -> PHP Content Type** and **add** a new file association for ***.ctp**. Then associate whatever type of editor you want Eclipse to use for syntax highlighting (php, html, etc.).

Comment: No, Preference>General>Content Types>Php  then add *.ctp

Comment: You need to restart eclipse for this to take effect.

Answer (score 6):

The comment by guru below is the best advice and worked for me.

Preferences > General > Content Types > PHP > add *.ctp

Recommend choosing PHP rather than HTML = even though they are view files with lots of HTML, you'll need the PHP type in order to see the PHP code segments clearly marked. You'll also be able to take advantage of the Source tools in the menus.

Answer (score 2):

IN some new version you can add this,  **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types ->Text -> PHP Content Type and add a new file association for *.ctp.**